# Using javascript var in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cookies

I have been trying use the "user" variable from this javascript so that I can use it in my php script. I want to echo the user variable in a php script. I am unable to do so as I have been trying to echo $user; .Also I am not able to find anything on internet to help me with this.

```
 alert("Welcome again " + user);
```

Instead of alert  I wish to print on screen Welcome again user(the name of user)
 Thank you

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>

    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

   function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
      var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
      for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
   }
   return "";
}

  function checkCookie() {
   var user=getCookie("username");
   if (user != "") {
       alert("Welcome again " + user);  
   } else {
      user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
      if (user != "" && user != null) {
          setCookie("username", user, 30);
      }
   }
 }

  </script>
  <?php echo  "Welcome back : ".$user;?>
  </head>
  <body onload="checkCookie()">
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: PLease explain what you mean by echo? echo is a PHP command and alert is javascript. And never the twain shall meet

Comment: sorry about that I have edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
<script>
    document.write("Welcome again " + user);
</script>
```

instead of alert if you want to print it on screen.

or do you really want to use PHP function echo?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to print the variable using PHP, you'll need to redirect the user to your PHP page with a url parameter like so :

`window.location.href="index.php?uname=+user+";`

And then get the parameter:

```
if(isset($_GET['uname'])) {
   $uname = $_GET['uname']; //after filtering and validating it of course
}
```

And then echo it:

```
echo $uname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have a huge misunderstanding how (and where) JavaScript and PHP are executed.

PHP is executed on the server when the client (most likely a Browser) requests the page. Afterwards the whole page (including your JavaScript) is send to the client, which is a completely other computer (usually).

Then the JavaScript is executed. Therefore there is no way the PHP code in your file is able to access the JavaScript variables.

You will definitely have to do it more like this:

- Client receives page from server
- Client executes JavaScript and somehow determines username.
- Client makes another request with the username as parameter to the server calling a PHP page.
- On the server you can handle the parameter which is the username, and do with it what you want.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you read it from cookies :

```
<?php echo  "Welcome back : ".($_COOKIE['user']!='' ? $_COOKIE['user'] : 'Guest');?>
```